# Postman crashing on large runs

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm using basic postman, no newman, just the build-in collection runner.

I have a loop with about 15 requests, 10 for the first iteration, and only 4 actually run every loop.

When using postman's collection-runner for more than 20 iterations, postman crashes, seemingly without reason. Any less iterations run fine without bugs or errors, and the environment variables don't stack up much after the initial requests.

Any ideas what could cause this and what would be a good workaround? (In the end I'm planning on running ~18000 iterations, so havind to restart after every 20 would be a problem.)

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak. How much RAM/CPU is being used when your collection is running?

Comment: Seems like it: postman seems to crash when it reaches about 2gb of ram (still having about 2gb ram spare).

Comment: I'm not sure if postman is designed to do load testing - maybe you need to use dedicated load testing tools.

Comment: I'm not even doing load testing: I'm migrating from one ticketing service to the next, so that's quite a lot of requests to handle with ~18k tickets. Seems like it'll work with newman though. I've tried using it, and it ran without any issues for 100 iterations (tickets).